# why fullUrlWithQuery adding field token to the url ? ? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5

I am trying to get full url with query in my blade but the `fullUrlWithQuery` adding field token at the end . Why this is happening and how can i stop it to add token to the url ?

My link generator is like this

```
 <li><a href="{{request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['price' =>'low-high'])}}">Low-High</a></li>
```

The url it is generating is

```
http://localhost:8000/c/fish?_token=exKaUn3U0yyIsblo7IB9ZXWFq4SqThHHXp9L6oot&price=low-high
```

Where as i was expecting it to generate

```
http://localhost:8000/c/fish?price=low-high
```

How can i prevent it from adding the token ? Any idea guyz

Comment: which version of laravel are you using

Comment: what is address bar value in your browser when you come to this view

Comment: i am using 5.6.
And address value is the same i put in the question

Comment: So you have a form with get method with action url of this view

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['sort' => 'priceLowToHigh']) }}
```

Comment: Please add a short description into your answer

Comment: Please, don't post code without an explanation as an answer. Try to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.